# Moving object to point a to point b smoothly

Tags: unity, movement, character

I am working on a problem where distance between the point A and B or given and object of interest should move smoothly from A to B.

I can control only control the speed of the object using this object should start slowly from point ease in and ease out at point B and need to exactly land on point B

I tried implementing ease in speed using distance covered however, at the beginning distance covered will be zero there will be *starting problem*. I solved starting problem using time elapsed as reference however this will not work precisely stoping object at point B, so I used distance remaining as a key to ease out.

This works for larger distance for smaller distance yet to tweak the code . Overall implementation messy not satisfied. Is there any generic solution to solve this problem? Note speed just a parameter controls overall movement of object, I can't say there is a exact relationship speed and distance covered.

(Unity developers: Note I am trying to control the movement of the character using three animation idle:speed=0, slowwalk:average speed=1, fastwalk: average speed=2)

Comment: I've interpolated using a sigmoid curve in the past. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to smoothly move an object from point A to point B.

I would use a coroutine:

```
private IEnumerator Move_Routine(Transform transform, Vector3 to, float speed)
{
    Vector3 from = transform.position;
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(from, to);
    float rate = speed / distance;

    for (float t = 0; t < 1; t += rate * Time.deltaTime)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(from, to, Mathf.SmoothStep(0f, 1f, t));
        yield return null;
    }

    // Ensure we end exactly at the destination, 
    // since the loop can end a fraction away.
    transform.position = to;
}
```

And I would start it by calling:

```
StartCoroutine(Move_Routine(this.transform, Vector3.one, 1));
```

Comment: He wants it to ease in and our rather than linear interpolate I think

Comment: @RobM my code is using a smooth step in there, and if that's not smooth enough you can always do this `Mathf.SmoothStep(0f, 1f, Mathf.SmoothStep(0f, 1f, Mathf.SmoothStep(0f, 1f, t)));`

Comment: Aha! SmoothStep. Wasn't aware that it performs a sigmoid type of interpolation.